# Dialing an emergency number in a foreign country using a satellite phone

Tags: emergencies, satellite-phones

I'm getting an Inmarsat phone for my time around San Pedro de Atacama in Chile to help me with emergencies.

What number do I dial if I have an issue?

I know 133 is the emergency number, but I don't think that works given my phone is a satellite phone.

I read that I need to look up the local police phone numbers, but that information is not published anywhere online!

Comment: 133 is the Police number in Chile, 131 is Ambulance and 132 Fire.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I found for most countries,

> If you have an Inmarsat satellite phone:
>
> 1. You will need to obtain the full international access code, country code, and phone number for the local fire, police, or ambulance depending upon the nature of the emergency and store it in your contacts.

[How to call emergency numbers from your Sat Phone](https://www.globaltelesat.co.uk/blog/how-to-call-emergency-numbers-from-your-sat-phone/)

and for the specific numbers for Chile.

**Note: I have not tested this, but the numbers should be correct.**

- [Full international access code from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_call_prefixes)

  > 1xx0, where xx is the international carrier selection code

  The Chilean carrier selection codes can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chilean_Carrier_Selection_Code).
- [Country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes)

  +56
- Phone numbers

  > Emergency Telephone Numbers (within Chile)
  >
  > Police (carabineros): 133
  >
  > Ambulance (ambulancia): 131
  >
  > Fire (bomberos): 132
  >
  > Sea Rescue (rescate del mar): 137
  >
  > Air Rescue (Busqueda y Salvamento Aereo): 138
  >
  > Mountain Rescue (rescate del montana): 699 4764

  [ExperienceChile.Org - Health & Safety](http://www.experiencechile.org/health-safety.html)

Comment: Are these numbers (133, 131...) any use given they're not local numbers and only work if you're on the network which I am not

Comment: @Joe The first source says you need  full international access code, country code, and phone number for the local fire, police, or ambulance to make the call in addition to the Chile specific numbers